# Why is my Web API routing being re-routed / falsely routed?

Tags: rest, controller, routes, repository, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two GET methods for a particular Controller / Repository:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetAllInventoryItems()
{
    return inventoryItemsRepository.GetAll();
}

[Route("api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")]
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch); 
}
```

Even though I've tried calling it all these ways from the client, with two arguments:

```
0)
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/inventoryItems/{0}/{1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri); 

1)
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/inventoryItems/?ID={0}&CountToFetch={1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri); 

2)
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/inventoryItems/ID={0}&CountToFetch={1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri);
```

...in each case it is still the first method (GetAll) that is being called. Why?

Here is my Repository code:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetAll()
{
    return inventoryItems;
}

public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.Id, ID)).Take(CountToFetch);
}
```

...and here is what's in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApiWithParameters",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}",
        defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

### UPDATE

This will show what I've tried as to routing calls to the Controller method I'm trying to have run:

```
//[HttpGet]
//[Route("api/{controller}/{ID:string}/{CountToFetch:int}")] <-- throws exception - won't run
//[Route("{controller}/{ID:string}/{CountToFetch:int}")] <-- throws exception - won't run
//[Route("inventoryItems/{ID:string}/{CountToFetch:int}")] <-- throws exception - won't run
//[Route("api/inventoryItems/{ID:string}/{CountToFetch:int}")] <-- throws exception - won't run
//[Route("api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")] // <-- runs, but is not called
[Route("api/InventoryItemsController/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")] // <-- runs, but is not called
//[Route("api/{controller}/{ID:string}/{CountToFetch:int}")] <-- throws exception - won't run
```

So the method that I *don't* want to be called is extremely robust: no matter how I decorate the other method, or how I call it, the undesired one runs.

### UPDATE 2

Wouldn't it have been easier to just allow the calling of Controller methods by name? e.g, given this Controller method:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch); //.Where(i => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

...why [c,w]ouldn't it be called from the client like so:

```
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/InventoryItemsController.GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID/{0}/{1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
```

???

ISTM that would be something that like that would have been a lot more intuitive.

### UPDATE 3

So what it boils down to is: Why is my GetAll() method getting called, when it takes no args?

Possibly the routing mechanism is getting confused because of lastIDFetched being set to an empty string:

```
string lastIDFetched = string.Empty;
```

...and so then formatargready_uri. which is assigned to this way:

```
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://locohost:28642/api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
```

...is at first:

```
"http://locohost:28642/api/InventoryItems//100"
```

(when I would expect it to be:

```
"http://locohost:28642/api/InventoryItems/""/100"
```

)

Could it be that the "missing" first arg is what's throwing the routing mechanism off, so that when it sees:

```
"http://locohost:28642/api/InventoryItems//100"
```

...it doesn't know whether to call this:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
{
    return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch); //.Where(i => string.Equals(p.Category, category,
```

StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

...or this:

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetAllInventoryItems()
{
    return inventoryItemsRepository.GetAll();
}
```

???

### UPDATE 4

When I comment out the other method, so that the client has no choice but to see the only existing method in the Controller/Repository, it does nothing on this line:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri);
```

(the two-arg method in the Controller still isn't called)

This is all that's in the Controller now:

```
public class InventoryItemsController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IInventoryItemRepository inventoryItemsRepository = new InventoryItemRepository();

    [Route("api/InventoryItems/{ID}/{CountToFetch:int}")] // <-- with this route decoration commented out or not, makes no difference
    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch); //.Where(i => string.Equals(p.Category, category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }    
}
```

Here is the corresponding Repository interface:

```
interface IInventoryItemRepository
{
    IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int CountToFetch); 
    InventoryItem Add(InventoryItem item);
}
```

...Repository implementation:

```
public class InventoryItemRepository : IInventoryItemRepository
{
    private readonly List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new List<InventoryItem>();

    public InventoryItemRepository()
    {
// code that populates inventoryItems by calling Add() not shown - it works, though
    } 

    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.Id, ID)).Take(CountToFetch);
    }

    public InventoryItem Add(InventoryItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }
        inventoryItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }        
}
```

...and the client code that calls it:

```
formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri);
```

### UPDATE 5

Well, I'll be darned like a holey sock. It seems to have been a problem with starting out with the empty string, after all. When I changed the initial value of lastIDFetched from string.Empty to "billy" it worked... Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? If I want to start from "scratch," what would I use rather than string.Empty? A blank space (" ") also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why are you having `{controller}` in the following attribute route? By decorating with an attribute route here you already are indicating the controller and action which should be hit, so remove `{controller}` here and replace it with the controller name.

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")]
public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int  CountToFetch)
{
   return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch); 
}
```

Requests 1) and 2) where you are using query string would not work because ID and CountToFetch are required route parameters.

Comment: "remove {controller} here and replace it with the controller name."
Come to think of it, why is it needed at all? Since it's in the Controller itself, shouldn't specifying it be redundant?

Comment: I don't understand why the parameters being required precludes them from being added via string.Format(), if that's what you're saying.

Comment: ""remove {controller} here and replace it with the controller name."
Are you saying it should be (class name is InventoryItemsController):

[Route("api/InventoryItemsController/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")]

Comment: i mean if your intention is to have users make requests like `api/inventoryItems/.../../`, then instead of the 'variable' `{controller}` here, you need to have 'inventoryItems'

Comment: I tried that already; none of my various permutations works - everything I do causes the "generic" GET method to be called instead. The commented out portions of my first Update show the various things I've tried along these lines.

Comment: you mean `[Route("api/InventoryItems/{ID}/{CountToFetch:int}")]` is not working?

Comment: This is not:
[Route("api/InventoryItems/{ID}/{CountToFetch}")]
I'll try it with the appended ":int"...Yep, just like all the other attempts - the other method in the controller is called, not the one I want to be called...